# Trouble importing android.support.v4 package

Tags: java, android, import

I'm trying to include the android-support-v4.jar into my command line android project. My import statement is simply:

```
import android.support.v4.NavUtils;
```

I've copied the jar from `$ANDROID_HOME/extras/android/support/v4/android-support-v4.jar` into my project's `libs/` folder but I still receive the following error upon building with `ant`:

```
package android.support.v4 does not exist
```

My understanding is that any jars placed in the `libs/` folder are automatically included in the projects classpath.

As requested, the output of `ls -l` on the root project folder is

```
-rw-r--r--   1 Nick  staff  1192  4 Jan 15:08 AndroidManifest.xml
-rw-r--r--   1 Nick  staff   696  4 Jan 12:12 ant.properties
drwxr-xr-x  17 Nick  staff   578  4 Jan 15:10 bin
-rw-r--r--   1 Nick  staff  3922  3 Jan 14:08 build.xml
drwxr-xr-x   4 Nick  staff   136  3 Jan 15:11 gen
drwxr-xr-x   3 Nick  staff   102  4 Jan 15:18 libs
-rw-r--r--   1 Nick  staff   441  3 Jan 14:08 local.properties
-rw-r--r--   1 Nick  staff   781  3 Jan 14:08 proguard-project.txt
-rw-r--r--   1 Nick  staff   563  3 Jan 14:08 project.properties
drwxr-xr-x   8 Nick  staff   272  3 Jan 14:08 res
drwxr-xr-x   3 Nick  staff   102  3 Jan 14:08 src
```

and the entire output from `ant debug` is

```
    Buildfile: /Users/Nick/DEVELOPMENT/PROJECTS/MyFirstApp/build.xml

-set-mode-check:

-set-debug-files:

-check-env:
 [checkenv] Android SDK Tools Revision 21.0.1
 [checkenv] Installed at /Users/Nick/Development/SDKS/android-sdk-macosx

-setup:
     [echo] Project Name: MyFirstApp
  [gettype] Project Type: Application

-set-debug-mode:

-debug-obfuscation-check:

-build-setup:
     [echo] Resolving Build Target for MyFirstApp...
[gettarget] Project Target:   Android 4.2
[gettarget] API level:        17
     [echo] ----------
     [echo] Creating output directories if needed...
     [echo] ----------
     [echo] Resolving Dependencies for MyFirstApp...
[dependency] Library dependencies:
[dependency] No Libraries
     [echo] ----------
     [echo] Building Libraries with 'debug'...
   [subant] No sub-builds to iterate on

-pre-build:

-code-gen:
[mergemanifest] No changes in the AndroidManifest files.
     [echo] Handling aidl files...
     [aidl] No AIDL files to compile.
     [echo] ----------
     [echo] Handling RenderScript files...
[renderscript] No RenderScript files to compile.
     [echo] ----------
     [echo] Handling Resources...
     [aapt] No changed resources. R.java and Manifest.java untouched.
     [echo] ----------
     [echo] Handling BuildConfig class...
[buildconfig] No need to generate new BuildConfig.

-pre-compile:

-compile:
    [javac] Compiling 1 source file to /Users/Nick/DEVELOPMENT/PROJECTS/MyFirstApp/bin/classes
    [javac] /Users/Nick/DEVELOPMENT/PROJECTS/MyFirstApp/src/com/example/myfirstapp/DisplayMessageActivity.java:9: package android.support.v4 does not exist
    [javac] import android.support.v4.NavUtils;
    [javac]                          ^
    [javac] /Users/Nick/DEVELOPMENT/PROJECTS/MyFirstApp/src/com/example/myfirstapp/DisplayMessageActivity.java:36: cannot find symbol
    [javac] symbol  : variable NavUtils
    [javac] location: class com.example.myfirstapp.DisplayMessageActivity
    [javac]                 NavUtils.navigateUpFromSameTask(this);
    [javac]                 ^
    [javac] 2 errors
```

Comment: oops, sorry I thought the problem was with eclipse.. This should work with ant though.. What version of adt do you have? Do you have the standard build.xml script or have you altered it?

Comment: I'm using ADT revision 21.0.1 (the latest one I believe) and I haven't altered the build.xml at all.

Comment: what OS are you running?

Comment: do an ls -l (osx/linux) or dir command from your main project folder. Also, maybe you could post the output from ant on here.

Comment: No problem. I posted both above.

Comment: solved.. had to create a test project to figure it out!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your import statement is incorrect, it should be:

```
import  android.support.v4.app.NavUtils;
```

Comment: Wow, this is beyond embarrassing. I guess this is what I get for trying to avoid using an IDE. Thanks for your time Matt! I'm sorry I don't have enough reputation to up vote your answer.

Comment: we've all done it at one time or another. I highly suggest an IDE though. I haven't written an import statement by hand in years! I always just create a variable with the type of class I need to import, which gives an error, which I can then right click on and it will suggest the classes to import (if it finds any).

Comment: For any one, still looking for perfect answer its here -http://stackoverflow.com/a/18300071/1225413