# Unable to import android.support.v4.apps.NavUtils

Tags: android, command-line, jar

After thoroughly searching here, I found the following question which exactly states the problem that I am facing.

[Trouble importing android.support.v4 package](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14164602/trouble-importing-android-support-v4-package)

However, the issue in that case was the imported package was wrong. In my case the package is correct and yet I am facing the same issue.

I have already wasted couple of days trying to figure out the solution.

One thing that I would like to add is that, I am trying to learn the command line execution for the purposes of automation so I dont want to use eclipse for the same purpose.

Going by the link on the support page, they talk about adding it in eclipse but havent mentioned how to do it via command line
http://developer.android.com/tools/extras/support-library.html#SettingUp

My android manifest mentions minsdkversion = 4 and targetsdkversion = 17 and I have already copied the android-support-v4.jar file into my project's "libs" folder but everything that i have tried so far has been in vain.

I am running this on windows 7 with JDK 1.6

Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Silly mistakes are common with beginners and I am no exception. The problem was an extra "s" in apps. It should be app in the package name. All I needed to do was to change the scope of debugging and move out from my code into the ANT script which showed me the problem.

Its amazing how putting the problem down in words gives you new avenues to dig which helped in my case. I think this is a good lesson for anybody attempting to start learning anything new.

I sincerely apologize to all those who attempted to find the problem. Hope you didn't spend a lot of time on this.

Thanks for reading though :)