# The import android.support cannot be resolved

Tags: java, android, package, rss-reader

I am trying to run the code provided [HERE](http://architects.dzone.com/articles/building-rss-reader-android)
I downloaded the code from their Github and imported into Android SDK, but it shows error at the lines

```
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity;
import android.support.v4.app.NavUtils;
```

in multiple files. However if I check the Android SDK Manager, the `Android Support Library` as well as the `Android Support Repository` in the Extras folder are both installed. I can also see the support folder and it's contents in the `SDK_INSTALL\sdk\extras\android\support` directory. It also has the v4 folder which also contains the `android-support-v4.jar` and the `src` folder. THen why is it still showing the error, how do I resolve it and how do I get that sample code running? THe sample code is for an RSS reader app, if that's relevant.

Comment: If you are using ADT 22, then "external library" might not be checked, go to project properties and check this option in build path.

Comment: I can't find this option. Is it in Builders or java Build path?

Comment: project > properties > java build path > order and export > check "Android Private Libraries"

Comment: The name of the IDE would have been a useful addition to this question.

Comment: The IDE was Android SDK downloaded from the Android Developers website. I am not sure which version it was though; it was probably the latest version at the time of posting this question

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26977608/appcompat-v7-errors-in-eclipse/27626241#27626241

Answer (score 286, accepted):

**Follow these steps:**

**For Eclipse:**

- Go to your Project's `Properties`
- Navigate to the `Java Build Path`
- Then go to the `Libraries` tab. There click the `Add External JARs` Button on the Right pane.
- Select the `android-support-v4.jar` file, usually the path for the **Jar file** is :
  ***YOUR_DRIVE\android-sdks\extras\android\support\v4\android-support-v4.jar***
- After adding `android-support-v4.jar` Library, navigate to the `Order and Export` tab and put check mark on the `android-support-v4` Library file.
- After doing the above, **Clean** the Project and **Build** it.
- *Problem Solved.*

**For Android Studio:**

*Short Version:*

- Add the following line to your `build.gradle` file: 
  `implementation 'com.android.support:support-v4:YOUR_TARGET_VERSION'`

*Long Version:*

- Go to File -> Project Structure
- Go to "Dependencies" Tab -> Click on the Plus sign -> Go to "Library dependency"
- Select the support library "support-v4 (com.android.support:support-v4:YOUR_TARGET_VERSION)"
- Navigate to your "build.gradle" inside your App Directory and double check if your desired Android Support Library has been added to your dependencies.
- Rebuild your project and now everything should work.

**Further reading regarding this Question:**

1. [Support Library - Android Dev](http://developer.android.com/tools/support-library/index.html)
2. [Recent Support Library Revisions](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/support-library/revisions.html)
3. [Support Library Packages](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/support-library/packages.html)
4. [What is an Android Support Library?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12926548/what-is-android-support-library)
5. [How do the Android Support Libraries work?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11641669/how-android-support-library-work)

Comment: Thanks :) Got this error after copying all my stuff to a new laptop, but installing Android on a different path

Comment: Thank you! You indeed solved my problem but, it is still wierd to me - My project used the v4 support lib just fine, and only after adding an external project which also uses the support lib it started happening. Why is that? Why didn't I have to add the v4 support lib before I added an external project?

Comment: Here is a link, that clearly answers your question :)
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12926548/what-is-android-support-library

Comment: @nylon100 That External Library may be using the features that are introduced in later version of Android SDKs and inorder to avail those features in your Project Support library is a must to add.

Comment: Thanks, that was it!! Why is it that the android system can't include this file when we ask for the import? I wasted an hour on this bug.

Comment: In the current version of IntelliJ it is hard to follow your instructions, because there are certain options named differently. But at the end it was a great help!

Comment: I see there's a new option if you right click on the project, android tools, "install support library". Does the configuration automagically :)

Comment: In Android Studio go to: File -> Project Structure -> Dependencies Tab -> Click + to add Library dependency -> Choose support-v4 from the list -> Click OK.

Comment: @evya Thanks for your response, i will update my Answer.

Comment: compile is obsolete and has been replaced with implementation now

Comment: I had the problem and followed the instructions. However, I could not resolve the problem until I realized that the `android.useAndroidX` and `android.enableJetifier` are set to `true` at `gradle.properties`. By making them `false`, my problem was solved.

Answer (score 15):

andorid-support-v4.jar is an external jar file that you have to import into your project.

This is how you do it in Android Studio:

Go to File -> Project Structure
[image]

Go to "Dependencies" Tab -> Click on the Plus sign -> Go to "Library dependency"
[image]

Select the support library "support-v4 (com.android.support:support-v4:23.0.1)"
[image]

Now to go your "build.gradle" file in your app and make sure the android support library has been added to your dependencies. Alternatively, you could've also just typed  `compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:23.0.1'`  directly into your `dependencies{}` instead of doing it through the GUI.

[image]

Rebuild your project and now everything should work. 
[image]

Answer (score 8):

Another way to solve the issue:

If you are using the support library, you need to add the `appcompat` lib to the project. [This link](https://developer.android.com/tools/support-library/setup.html#add-library) shows how to add the support lib to your project.

Assuming you have added the support lib earlier but you are getting the mentioned issue, you can follow the steps below to fix that.

1. Right click on the project and navigate to **Build Path > Configure Build Path**.
2. On the left side of the window, select **Android**. You will see something like this:

[image]

3. You can notice that no library is referenced at the moment. Now click on the **Add** button shown at the bottom-right side. You will see a pop up window as shown below.

[image]

4. Select the `appcompat` lib and press **OK**. (Note: The lib will be shown if you have added them as mentioned earlier). Now you will see the following window:

[image]

5. Press **OK**. That's it. The lib is now added to your project (notice the red mark) and the errors relating inclusion of support lib must be gone.

Comment: @downvoter.. a brief kind information abt the reason for downvote will be highly appreciated. This'll help me in future to make my ans better in helping others. I've shared what I'd experienced to help future readers and the ans pretty much related to the question.

Answer (score 4):

For me they were appearing when i transferred code manually to another laptop. Just do

> File>Invalidate Cache/Restart

click on 'Invalidate Cache and Restart' and your are done.

Answer (score 3):

I followed the instructions above by Gene in Android Studio 1.5.1 but it added this to my build.gradle file:

```
compile 'platforms:android:android-support-v4:23.1.1'
```

so I changed it to:

```
compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:23.1.1'
```

And it started working.

Answer (score 2):

This issue may also occur if you have multiple versions of the same support library `android-support-v4.jar`. If your project is using other library projects that contain different-2 versions of the support library. To resolve the issue keep the same version of support library at each place.

Answer (score 1):

**This is very easy step to import any 3rd party lib or jar file into your project**

1. Copy **android-support-v4.jar** file from
   **your_drive\android-sdks\extras\android\support\v4\android-support-v4.jar**

   ***or*** copy from your existing project's bin folder.

   **or any third party .jar file**
2. paste copied **jar** file into **lib** folder
3. right click on this jar file and then click on **build Path->Add to
   Build Path** [image]
4. even still you are getting error in your project then **Clean the
   Project and Build it.**

Answer (score 1):

I have resolved it by deleting `android-support-v4.jar` from my Project. Because `appcompat_v7` already have a copy of it.

**If you have already import appcompat_v7 but still the problem doesn't solve. then try it.**

Answer (score 0):

Android Studio 2.2.3
Linux Mint 18.1

Inside your 'project view' open Gradle Scripts -> build.gradle(Module:app) and put your mouse pointer inside the word dependencies.

Click on the light bulb and click "add library dependency" and for me all the libraries I wanted were listed there.

example libraries that came up for me:
  compile 'com.android.support:gridlayout-v7:25.1.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v13:25.1.0'

I am now looking to add android support by default in Gradles default configuration.