# Android: what replaced android.support.v4.app.NavUtils in later APIs?

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-support-library

I'm programming an app for tablets, API level 13 or higher. Therefore I do not need the support library, i.e. `android.support.v4.app.Fragment` has been replaced by `android.app.Fragment` and similar.

In the support library there was a neat class [`android.support.v4.app.NavUtils`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/app/NavUtils.html), but I cannot find any equivalent class in the higher APIs. So what replaced it or its methods? How can I use its methods without importing the support library? Is it possible?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Android version above & including Jelly Beans have the NavUtils incorporated into the Activity class. So, there is no separate framework lib for that.

Comment: But Honeycomb (API level 13) not yet?

Comment: Not for HoneyComb and even Icecream Sandwich

Comment: For any one, still looking for perfect answer its here -http://stackoverflow.com/a/18300071/1225413

Comment: With androidx, `NavUtils` can be imported as `androidx.core.app.NavUtils`