# How can I get the android-support-v4.jar file (from Android Support Library) on Linux?

Tags: android, linux

Reading "[The import android.support cannot be resolved](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18299898/the-import-android-support-cannot-be-resolved)" I can see that I require a file named `android-support-v4.jar` .  Reading http://developer.android.com/tools/support-library/setup.html I can see that I need the SDK Manager.  But where can I just get the file?

Comment: you should have the sdk manager. it comes with any sdk installer, and it is what you use to install platforms, which you need to compile against. It also runs headless, in case that is what you are looking for.

Answer (score 15):

The directory has been removed. Now it is under 
`../extras/m2respository/com/android/support/support-v4/21.0.0...` and so on.
The file name is now support-v4-20.0.0.jar and so on.

Comment: I didn't find a Jar file, there you can find aar files

Comment: You can extract the JAR from the AAR.  I made a quick video. 
https://youtu.be/wT4FvH7OYJo

Comment: @Sean Novak, yeah, you can.  But it looks like those aar files do not represent standalone packages.  I think they are just patches.  So it looks like in order to get one full jar, one has to unpack many those aar files..

Comment: @SeanNovak This https://youtu.be/wT4FvH7OYJo video isn't available anymore. :(

Answer (score 14):

Officially, you can get the library downloading the SDK, find your SDK directory, and its located under:

`[sdk-dir]/extras/android/support/v4/android-support-v4.jar`

*Unofficially*, here's a java2s-hosted [direct download](http://www.java2s.com/Code/JarDownload/android-support/android-support-v4.jar.zip).

Comment: Extras are not included with the SDK, at least not as of this writing. There is a separate "Extras -> Android Support Repository" that must be installed from the SDK Manager.

Comment: I am trying to modify a project (Gradle project) that uses that unresolved import. It does not help me to download "Android Support repository", it end up in a maven folder inside the Android SDK. The project tries to import "android.Support.*".The`android.jar` otherwise functional.

Answer (score 2):

You can find this jar under your android SDK dir:

`/extras/android/support/v4/android-support-v4.jar`

and a copy here:

`/extras/android/support/v7/appcompat/libs/android-support-v4.jar`

Comment: What is the difference between `sdk\extras\android\support\v4\android-support-v4.jar` and `sdk\extras\android\m2repository\com\android\support\support-v4\19.1.0\support-v4-19.1.0.jar` mentioned @Mahdi-Malv?

Answer (score 1):

The android-support-v4.jar file is located in

> /extras/android/support/v4/android-support-v4.jar

Copy and paste this file to your Project libs folder and the add this jar to your build path by

1. Right Click on your project and Click on Properties
2. Go to Java Build Path > Libraries > Add jar > Browse the jar in your project libs folder and add it.
3. Go to order and export tab, and tick(check) on the library.

Answer (score 0):

1. `cd android-sdks/tools`
2. Run `./android sdk`
3. Click "Install X packages"