# appcompat_v7 errors in eclipse

Tags: android, eclipse

i'm new to android programming .i have just installed eclipse and sdk and adt plugin .evereting works fine when i import other project. but when i create a new project it give me a lot of errors.

here are the errors:

```
*Description    Resource    Path    Location    Type
Unknown error: java.lang.NullPointerException   appcompat_v7        Unknown Android Packaging Problem

*ActionBarActivity cannot be resolved to a type MainActivity.java   /Testsaid/src/com/example/testsaid  line 32 Java Problem

*The method getMenuInflater() is undefined for the type MainActivity    MainActivity.java   /Testsaid/src/com/example/testsaid  line 19 Java Problem

*R cannot be resolved to a variable MainActivity.java   /Testsaid/src/com/example/testsaid  line 19 Java Problem

*The method onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem) of type MainActivity must override or implement a supertype method  MainActivity.java   /Testsaid/src/com/example/testsaid  line 24 Java Problem
error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'Theme.AppCompat.Light'. styles.xml  /Testsaid/res/values    line 7  Android AAPT Problem
*R cannot be resolved to a variable MainActivity.java   /Testsaid/src/com/example/testsaid  line 29 Java Problem
*The method onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu) of type MainActivity must override or implement a supertype method    MainActivity.java   /Testsaid/src/com/example/testsaid  line 17 Java Problem
error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'Theme.AppCompat.Light'. styles.xml  /Testsaid/res/values-v11    line 7  Android AAPT Problem
*R cannot be resolved to a variable MainActivity.java   /Testsaid/src/com/example/testsaid  line 13 Java Problem
*ActionBarActivity cannot be resolved to a type MainActivity.java   /Testsaid/src/com/example/testsaid  line 12 Java Problem
*The method onCreate(Bundle) of type MainActivity must override or implement a supertype method MainActivity.java   /Testsaid/src/com/example/testsaid  line 11 Java Problem
*ActionBarActivity cannot be resolved to a type MainActivity.java   /Testsaid/src/com/example/testsaid  line 8  Java Problem
*The import android.support.v7 cannot be resolved   MainActivity.java   /Testsaid/src/com/example/testsaid  line 3  Java Problem
*error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar'.  styles.xml  /Testsaid/res/values-v14    line 8  Android AAPT Problem
```

here are the code of main activity:

```
package com.example.saidg;

import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;

public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
}
```

i noticed that most of them come from values folders. they are marked with a little red cross

i also noticed that a new project has been created named appcompat. i saw other posts about this problem  but they didn't help. the target sdk is already set to android 21 in project properties file.

thanks

Comment: adding the error messages could probably help anyone trying to help you

Comment: please post some code where errors are.. and what errors msgs? Logcat... appcompat_v7 is a support library thats is created.

Comment: Ok i will add errors

Comment: Also post some codes especially import statements where errors are occuring..

Comment: try deleting imports of menu, menu item, inflater which are imported from appcompat library and import them again

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Go to

```
Right click your Project --> Properties --> Android --> 
(on the right side Library Section) (Click) Add --> Select appcompat_v7 (click ok and Apply)
```

Now clean and build all Projects.

Comment: i found a red cross mark next to appcompat library. i reimported it and it becoms green but.errors are still there. i checked the library section again. and i found it red again.

Comment: why arn't you posting code...? show your MainActivity.java at least! If you want to get help.

Comment: Ok. i will add execuse me but it is just a default hello world project. with default setting .i will post it at description

Comment: Errors at importing ActionBarActivity...? and? ActionBarActivity cannot be resolved to a type MainActivity.java ; This occurs when it is unable to import ActionBarActivity or there are two  instances of android-support-v7-appcompat.jar

Comment: there is an additional apcompat jar in my project lib/ folder i deleted it. and clean the project and build. and the project is now working

Comment: yes dont keep two instances. And when you update the library only update at one place ie appcompat_v7..

Comment: @saidTagnit.. this is what I said as answer see my second solution where project created normally. Said this because you accepted the other answer.

Comment: @Alexander he made appcompat_v7 as library as i said above... then he was having two instances of android-support-v7-appcompat.jar... that was the second problem.. he removed one of them that solved it

Comment: @Alexander you talked about a whole folder. but the problem is related just to one .jar file. but Mohammed ali mentioned the exact .jar file in his comment. that why i marked his answer. anyway thank you too alexander for giving your time trying to help. i appreciate it.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a new project without creating activities. 
--> untick create activities.

Or create project normally. This will create new Appcompat folder. Then you can delete the new one and change the library to the old one from the properties of the project.

One other possibility for errors is conflicting with Android support library. You can delete it from the libs folder inside your project folder.

Comment: i treid this. when doing this it doesn't create appcompat folder but  same errors stay there

Comment: Did you try all three ways