# Eclipse add dependencies android.support.v4

Tags: android, eclipse, sdk, android-support-library

I got an error says "import android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout" not resolved. So tried to googling and found this [The import android.support cannot be resolved](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18299898/the-import-android-support-cannot-be-resolved) but it doesnt solve my problem..

I have installed android support repository in SDK Manager and there is no android.support.v4.jar in the folder.

folder
sdk\extras\android\m2repository\com\android\support\support-v4\All Versions (API) of support-v4 (none of it works)

Comment: Switch to Android Studio

Comment: move to android studio...development in eclipse is very difficult.