# i am getting an error : import android.support cannot be resolved at the line:

Tags: android, android-support-library, android-library, android-sdk-2.3

```
import android.support.v4.app.NotificationCompatApi21;
```

> Any idea what I can do to resolve it

NOTE: I have added the android-support-v4.jar to my project and i look through library, there is no class as NotificationCompatApi21.

Comment: See this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18299898/the-import-android-support-cannot-be-resolved

Comment: you may added it incorrectly.